# Express Cors missing allow credentials

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, cors

I have the following config for my express server:

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import helmet from "helmet";
import morgan from "morgan";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import categoryRoutes from "./routes/category.js";
import subCategoryRoutes from "./routes/subCategory.js";
import expenseRoutes from "./routes/expense.js";
import userRoutes from "./routes/user.js";
import { authMiddleware } from "./middleware/authMiddleware.js";

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(helmet.crossOriginResourcePolicy({ policy: "cross-origin" }));

app.use(morgan("common"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: *********************,
    credentials: true,
  })
);

app.use("/category", authMiddleware, categoryRoutes);
app.use("/subCategory", authMiddleware, subCategoryRoutes);
app.use("/expense", authMiddleware, expenseRoutes);
app.use("/user", userRoutes);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000;

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(async () => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server running on port: ${PORT}`);
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(`${error} connecting to DB`);
  });
```

But for any route that's not "/user", I'm getting a "CORS Missing Allow Credentials" error with the following request headers:

```
Accept
    */*
Accept-Encoding
    gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language
    en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection
    keep-alive
Cookie
    jwt=*************************
Host
    *************************
Origin
    https://*********************
Referer
    https:/**********************/
Sec-Fetch-Dest
    empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode
    cors
Sec-Fetch-Site
    cross-site
TE
    trailers
User-Agent
    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0
```

I am using a middleware for the other routes so maybe that might be causing an issue,
if so, here it is:

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export const authMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { id, token } = req.cookies;
  console.log(id, token);
  try {
    if (id) {
      req.userId = id;
    res.setHeader(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
      "**************************"
    );
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
      next();
    }

    if (token) {
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
      if (decoded) {
        const userId = decoded.id;
        req.userId = userId;
    res.setHeader(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
      "**************************"
    );
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
        next();
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Not authorized!");
  }
};
```

I'm thinking my cors and helmet configs are incorrectly setup but here is one of the endpoints I hit, I don't have any headers set on it's response:

```
router.get("/expenses/", async (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.userId;
  console.log(userId);

  try {
    const expenses = await Expense.find({
      userId: userId,
    })
      .populate("subCategory")
      .populate("category")
      .exec();

    const mappedExpenses = expenses.map((expense) => ({
      id: expense._id,
      date: expense.date,
      price: expense.price,
      userId: expense.userId,
      category: expense.category.name,
      subCategory: expense.subCategory.name,
    }));
    console.log("user expenses: ", mappedExpenses);
    res.status(200).json(mappedExpenses);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});
```

It might be useful to add that the I'm getting a 502 bad gateway on the /expense/expenses request and a referrer policy of strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Lastly, I'm using rtk query to make these api calls with the following basequery:

```
baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({baseUrl: import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL, credentials: 'include'}),
```

The env var matches the server url so no issue there and the frontend login component sets cookies like so:

```
loginUser(values)
            .unwrap()
            .then((res) => {
              console.log(res._id);
              setCookie("id", res._id, {
                path: "/",
                sameSite: "none",
                secure: true,
              });

              toast.success("logged in!");

              navigate("/dashboard", { replace: true });
            })
            .catch((e) => {
              console.log(e);
            });
```

Comment: Don't mix the `cors` module with home brewed `setHeader` calls for `Access-Control-etc` headers. It will only confuse matters.

Comment: Okay, should I remove the cors module?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using the cors module over homebrewing a CORS implementation

Comment: Okay so I guess I'm being redundant, app.use(
  cors({
    origin: *********************,
    credentials: true,
  })
) sets the response headers already, but will it also set the same headers for each individual route?

Comment: I tried implicitly setting origin to "*" by not including the origin prop, but I got an error saying that it can't be "*" while the credentials header is set to 'include' in my rtk basequery

Comment: Update: it's an issue with my middleware. Without the trycatch and if I set the userId manually, data is fetched normally. Which means it's a problem with the cookies, most likely undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Happy to report I spent 10 hours to only find in the end that the cookie I was setting on login was "jwt" and I was searching for a cookie named "token" in my middleware.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure about it but it might have something to with setting the cookie to secure.

```
setCookie("id", res._id, {
                path: "/",
                sameSite: "none",
                secure: true,
          });
```

In this case, you should not have * as allowed origin. I think configuring cors might fix it.

allowedOrigin.js:

```
const allowedOrigins = ["your-frontend-app-port"];

module.exports = allowedOrigins;
```

corsOptions.js:

```
const allowedOrigins = require("./allowedOrigins");

const corsOptions = {
  origin: (origin, callback) => {
    if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS"));
    }
  },
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
};

module.exports = corsOptions;
```

In the index/server.js file

```
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

**NOT SURE ABOUT IT. JUST AN INTUITION.**

Answer (score 1):

Remove this or make it false,
**credentials: true**

backend as well as front end